# Understanding the source code of memcpy()

Tags: c

```
00018 void *memcpy(void *dst, const void *src, size_t len)
00019 {
00020         size_t i;
00021 
00022         /*
00023          * memcpy does not support overlapping buffers, so always do it
00024          * forwards. (Don't change this without adjusting memmove.)
00025          *
00026          * For speedy copying, optimize the common case where both pointers
00027          * and the length are word-aligned, and copy word-at-a-time instead
00028          * of byte-at-a-time. Otherwise, copy by bytes.
00029          *
00030          * The alignment logic below should be portable. We rely on
00031          * the compiler to be reasonably intelligent about optimizing
00032          * the divides and modulos out. Fortunately, it is.
00033          */
00034 
00035         if ((uintptr_t)dst % sizeof(long) == 0 &&
00036             (uintptr_t)src % sizeof(long) == 0 &&
00037             len % sizeof(long) == 0) {
00038 
00039                 long *d = dst;
00040                 const long *s = src;
00041 
00042                 for (i=0; i<len/sizeof(long); i++) {
00043                         d[i] = s[i];
00044                 }
00045         }
00046         else {
00047                 char *d = dst;
00048                 const char *s = src;
00049 
00050                 for (i=0; i<len; i++) {
00051                         d[i] = s[i];
00052                 }
00053         }
00054 
00055         return dst;
00056 }
```

I was just going through an implementation of `memcpy`, to understand how it differs from using a loop. But I couldn't see any difference between using a loop rather than `memcpy`, as `memcpy` uses loop again internally to copy.

I couldn't understand `if` part they do for integers — `i < len/sizeof(long)`. Why is this calculation required?

Comment: Where's this code come from? I've seen better optimized memcpy implementations...

Comment: @Maxime: how would you know: you don't even know the target processor (or compiler for that matter)!

Comment: @Angus, judging by your answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11772553/why-padding-is-not-happening-in-this-case/11773431#11773431 you seem to understand alignment. The `long` is a processor word and the address needs to be processor word aligned for a faster copy (most architectures do faster copies on aligned data). If you can't do it, then do it slowly, byte by byte. There are good answers below.

Comment: @OlofForshell because if not aligned and not a multiple of `sizeof(long)`, it does a slow copy. It's easy to imagine to copy some aligned data with a size that is not equal to a multiple of `sizeof(long)` and finish with a slow copy. But you are true, for very specific target processors and use cases, this could be better. But this code aims to be portable and for the majority of cases, this could be improved.

Comment: Doesn't this function break aliasing rules (accessing memory via a long* that wasn't necessarily declared to be long) and therefore is undefined behavour?

Comment: @jcoder the implementation's implementation doesn't have to follow any rules. It would be a violation if you copied this code into a function of your own name and used it as such.

Answer (score 19):

> I couldn't understand if part they do for integers. i < len/sizeof(long). Why is this calculation required ?

Because they are copying words, not individual bytes, in this case (as the comment says, it is an optimization - it requires less iterations and the CPU can handle word aligned data more efficiently).

`len` is the **number of bytes** to copy, and `sizeof(long)` is the **size of a single word**, so the number of elements to copy (means, loop iterations to execute) is `len / sizeof(long)`.

Comment: Word-aligned copy does not actually depend on CPU. It depends on how wired is the RAM.

Comment: @m0skit0 I would say it depends on the architecture - there are CPUs which can not even access data at non-aligned addresses, and there are ones which can access individual bytes at all addresses, but then these accesses might be much slower than accessing an aligned address

Comment: Yes I know. And precisely that's because on how wired is the RAM ;) Anyway, this is a detail. Your answer is correct.

Comment: Probably should have said "architecture" in my answer instead of "CPU", as you did :)

Answer (score 6):

> to understand how it differs from using a loop. But I couldn't any
>   difference of using a loop rather than memcpy, as memcpy uses loop
>   again internally to copy

Well then it uses a loop. Maybe other implementations of libc doesn't do it like that. Anyway, what's the problem/question if it does use a loop? Also as you see it does more than a loop: it checks for alignment and performs a different kind of loop depending on the alignment.

> I couldn't understand if part they do for integers. i <
>   len/sizeof(long). Why is this calculation required ?

This is checking for memory word alignment. If the destination and source addresses are word-aligned, and the length copy is multiple of word-size, then it performs an aligned copy by word (`long`), which is faster than using bytes (`char`), not only because of the size, but also because most architectures do word-aligned copies much faster.

Comment: what i do using loops is also word aligned(int -> 4 bytes).

Comment: It's only worth doing it by 4 bytes if conditions apply. Otherwise word copy might be slower than byte copy. In fact in some architectures you can only copy memory zones do it if they are word aligned, otherwise it's an hardware exception (e.g. MIPS IIRC).

Answer (score 6):

`len%sizeof(long)` checks if you are trying to copy full-longs not a part of `long`.

```
00035    if ((uintptr_t)dst % sizeof(long) == 0 &&
00036             (uintptr_t)src % sizeof(long) == 0 &&
00037             len % sizeof(long) == 0) {
00038 
00039                 long *d = dst;
00040                 const long *s = src;
00041 
00042                 for (i=0; i<len/sizeof(long); i++) {
00043                         d[i] = s[i];
00044                 }
```

checks for alignment and if true, copies fast(`sizeof(long)` bytes at a time).

```
00046    else {
00047                 char *d = dst;
00048                 const char *s = src;
00049 
00050                 for (i=0; i<len; i++) {
00051                         d[i] = s[i];
00052                 }
00053    }
```

this is for the mis-aligned arrays (slow copy (1 byte at a time))

Answer (score 4):

```
for (i=0; i<len/sizeof(long); i++) {
    d[i] = s[i];
}
```

In this for loop, every time a `long` is copied, there are a total size of `len` to copy, that's why it needs `i<len/sizeof(long)` as the condition to terminate the loop.

Answer (score 0):

> I was just going through an implementation of `memcpy`, to understand how it differs from using a loop. But I couldn't see any difference between using a loop rather than memcpy, as `memcpy` uses loop again internally to copy.

Loop (control statements) is one of the basic elements adjacent to if (decision statements) and few other such things. So the question here is not about what is the difference between normal looping and using `memcpy`.

`memcpy` just aids your task by providing you with a ready to use API call, instead of having you to write 20 lines of code for a petty thing. If you wish so, you can choose to write your own code to provide you with the same functionality.

Second point as already pointed out earlier is that, the **optimization** it provides between `long` data type and other types. Because in `long` it is *copying a block of data* at once what we call a word instead of copying byte by byte which would take longer time. In case of long, **the same operation that would require 8 iterations to complete**, `memcpy` **does it in a single iteration by copying the word at once**.

Answer (score 0):

As if you see assembly code of memcpy it show that in 32 bit system each register is 32 bit it can store 4 byte at a time, if you will copy only one byte in 32 bit register, CPU need extra Instruction cycle.

If len/count is aliged in the multiple of 4 , we can copy 4 byte in one cycle

```
    MOV FROM, R2
    MOV TO,   R3
    MOV R2,   R4
    ADD LEN,  R4
CP: MOV (R2+), (R3+) ; "(Rx+)" means "*Rx++" in C
    CMP R2, R4
    BNE CP
```