# strcpy vs memcpy for copying char * with known size

Tags: c, memcpy, literals, strcpy

I don't care about the NULL terminator so I have two choices:

```
strcpy(createTabStmt, "CREATE TABLE "); //shorter and more readable code
```

Or

```
memcpy(createTabStmt, "CREATE TABLE ", sizeof ("CREATE TABLE ") - 1); //faster?
```

Is the `memcpy` version always faster?

--

If that's true, then I think a macro can make the readability as good as `strcpy`:

```
#define MEMCPY_LITERAL(ptr,literal) memcpy(ptr, literal, sizeof (literal) - 1)
```

--

I thought the `memcpy` version has one more constant `sizeof ("CREATE TABLE ") - 1`. So it uses more space. Is that true?

Comment: Is this the bottleneck in your program?  If not, you are worrying about a negligible performance difference for no real gain.  Premature optimization is a bad thing.  Premature micro-optimization is horrible.

Comment: What does `sizeof ("CREATE TABLE ")` evaluate to?

Comment: They're not equivalent. The `strcpy` form writes one extra byte. I'm not sure if you care, but if not, why are you going to the trouble to subtract one in the second version?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7776085/why-is-memcpy-and-memmove-faster-than-pointer-increments

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: The size of the object: 14.

Comment: I doubt there's any noticeable performance difference between the two. On the general case `memcpy` may be a better (secure) alternative though since it does not rely on the string terminator character.

Comment: @R I assumed that literal is char* and this would be size of pointer.

Comment: The answer of witch is faster depends on the implementation. Use the function for which it's intended to, `strcpy` for string and `memcpy` for raw buffers.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan `sizeof` is correctly used (yields the size of the object, 14)

Comment: @cdhowie Let's say I'm not doing software engineering or any optimization. It's only a question about characteristics of C programming language.

Comment: `sizeof ("CREATE TABLE ") - 1);` : You should not make `-1` in this case. (this meaning would be different to `strcpy` version.)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I mentioned "I don't care about the NULL terminator", `-1` doesn't matters to me in this case.

Comment: It can be said to be faster than always just for NUL.

Comment: @Griddoor But this isn't a question about the C programming language really, it's more of a question about the speed of specific functions in the particular implementation you are using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the source is a literal, I would expect any decent optimizing compiler to do the same for either one (modulo the fact that your `memcpy` version is writing one byte fewer): either call `memcpy` with an appropriate size, or generate inline code to store the the contents to the destination directly. You can verify this with gcc and compatible compilers by using `-S` instead of `-c` to output assembly language, or by disassembling the output program.

Answer (score 0):

Strcpy will be heavily optimized, my expectation is that you will be unable to measure a difference between these two statements. That, and the database is going to do thousands and thousands of things on a `CREATE TABLE`, so you should be optimizing for readability here. Just use strcpy, people know what it is, the compiler knows what it is, it works perfectly for what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If size is known, normally a non-naive implementation of `memcpy` is faster than strcpy, since it takes profit of the CPU's data bus size. For example, if you are to copy 16 bytes, a good implementation in a 64 bit CPU will break down the data transfer in two 8 byte copies. This is achieved by casting the source and destination pointers as 64 bit variable pointers, and then reading/writing memory with two iterations.

Check this link:
[Understanding the source code of memcpy()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591624/understanding-the-source-code-of-memcpy)

Answer (score 0):

as a ground rule you should use strcpy for strings and memcpy for data.
Once you start changing it for negligible performance saving, you make the code unreadable and confusing.

This also goes for macros - you should also avoid them as well, as they can cause compile errors for anyone that rewrites your code(or for you several months/years from now)

This goes in most cases, unless you write code where the performance is crucial(most cases it isn't)

Comment: Disagree with "as a ground rule you should use strcpy for strings and memcpy for data.".  String manipulation is very commonly a source of overall performance issues   so "changing it for negligible performance saving" is a false premise.  OP's example may be over-simplistic as so to  support your idea concerning  negligible performance saving, yet the title question is still a real valid concern and not answered here.