# Using memcpy method

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memcpy

I m looking for how to write a function like memcpy. Method that copy integers or chars from one array to other.
What i mean, its to use memcpy, without using it. But in my case it does not work.

```
void Memcpy( void *from, void *to, int dimension, int length ) {

   if(dimension == sizeof(char)){
      char *copyFrom = (char *)from;
      char *copyTo = (char *)to;

      for(int i = length; i < length; i++)
         copyTo[i] = copyFrom[i];
   }


   if(dimension == sizeof(int)){
      int *copyFrom = (int *)from;
      int *copyTo = (int *)to;

      for(int i = length; i < length; i++)
         copyTo[i] = copyFrom[i];
   }
}
```

{Thank you for help =)}

Comment: Welcome to SO. You forgot to mention where you are stuck. What exactly is your problem? Show us your current effort for your copy function and we can help fixing the problem.

Comment: Actually, `memcpy` does the job.

Comment: Are you trying to recreate memcpy?

Comment: Yes, but without using it

Comment: Have you already read https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/41094/memcpy-implementation and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591624/understanding-the-source-code-of-memcpy ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
void copyOfArray( void *from, void *to, int dimension, int length ) {
     memcpy(to, from, dimension * length);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is really achieved with `memcpy`, there is no need to reinvent it. For your convinience you can wrap it with `copy_of_array` or even wrap `copy_of_array` with `copy2` (as long as arrays are staticaly allocated).

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define copy2(src, dst, count, shift) copy_of_array(src, dst, count, sizeof(src[0]), shift)

copy_of_array (void * src,
               void * dst,
               int    count,
               int    elem_size,
               int    shift)
{
  memcpy (dst, (char*)src + elem_size * shift, count * elem_size);
}

int main() {
  int i;
  int ione[4] = { 1, 2, 3, 4};
  int itwo[2] = { 0, 0 };
  char cone[4] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};
  char ctwo[2] = { 'x', 'y' };
  copy_of_array(ione, itwo, 1, sizeof(int), 3);
  for (i=0; i<2; i++ )
    printf("%d ", itwo[i] );

  copy2(cone, ctwo, 1, 3);
  for (i=0; i<2; i++ )
    printf("%c ", ctwo[i] );
}
```