# Union and structure for USB driver implementation

Tags: c

I am trying to create host usb drivers  for a printer device  using the PIC32mx  series .
I am using the Microchip Library Application sample example .
Wherein iI see that in order to send the BDT, the below mentioned  structure is used.
Now the BDT should be in all 8 bytes as documented in the Application note , 
But when I check the size of the BD_ENTRY union variable I  see that it is different- 12 bytes. It should be 8 bytes if i am right.
I tried to compile this particular  part of  the same code using Mikroc and simulated it using proteus and I find the byte length (sizeof) to be 8 bytes.

I am a bit confused, also I am new to the world of pointers, structures and unions.

```
typedef union _BD_STAT {
    BYTE Val;
    struct {
        //If the CPU owns the buffer then these are the values
        unsigned BC8:1;         //bit 8 of the byte count
        unsigned BC9:1;         //bit 9 of the byte count
        unsigned BSTALL:1;      //Buffer Stall Enable
        unsigned DTSEN:1;       //Data Toggle Synch Enable
        unsigned INCDIS:1;      //Address Increment Disable
        unsigned KEN:1;         //BD Keep Enable
        unsigned DTS:1;         //Data Toggle Synch Value
        unsigned UOWN:1;        //USB Ownership
    };

    struct {
        //if the USB module owns the buffer then these are
        // the values
        unsigned :2;
        unsigned PID0:1;        //Packet Identifier
        unsigned PID1:1;
        unsigned PID2:1;
        unsigned PID3:1;
        unsigned :1;
    };

    struct {
        unsigned :2;
        unsigned PID:4;         //Packet Identifier
        unsigned :2;
    };
} BD_STAT;    

typedef union __attribute__ ((packed))__BDT {
    //typedef union __BDT{
    struct __attribute__ ((packed)) {
        //struct   
        BD_STAT     STAT;
        WORD        CNT:10;
        WORD        ADR;                      
        WORD        ADRH;                   
    };
    struct __attribute__ ((packed)) {
        //struct   
        DWORD       res  :16;
        DWORD       count:10;
    };

    DWORD           w[2];
    WORD            v[4];
    QWORD           Val;
} BDT_ENTRY;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11770451/what-is-the-meaning-of-attribute-packed-aligned4/11772340#11772340

Comment: structure padding confuse you so batter to remove it.

Comment: I would have thought you'd get 16 as the size of BDT_ENTRY.  How many bytes are there in a WORD, DWORD and QWORD?

Comment: I checked QWORD sizeoff it is 8 bytes , i also checked by removing the -attrib and packed things .. but they are supposed to remove the padding , could it be that  i am useing free version of mplab c32 compiler , it  does not provide optimize code .. just guessing .

Comment: When i remove attrib packed it comes to 16 bytes size of BDT_ENTRY and with the packed attrib it comes to 10 bytes .

Answer (score 0):

Give all of those anonymous structures names (temporarily) so that you can check them with `sizeof`.  One issue I've seen with bitfields is that some compilers (including gcc, at least one time when it bit me) are overly influenced by the base type of a bitfield.  So those `unsigned bit:1` bitfields that are unioned with a `Byte` in `BD_STAT` might be slicing their bits out of a 4-byte `unsigned` causing `BD_STAT` to be too large.  If you verify that with `sizeof` try changing the base type to `Byte` and see if it packs smaller.

Answer (score 0):

In `BD_STAT` use `unsigned char` instead of `unsigned`.
Bit fields always have the size of the underlying type and not the sum of their sizes. So `BD_STAT` is 4 bytes long.