# Why structure size is incorrect

Tags: c++, c, data-structures

I just tried to check how memory is allocated to structure objects, its taking more space what i expected. I am using 64 bit windows OS and Microsoft visual studio 2010(i think its 32 bit), so can some explain why is its printing 52 bytes ?

```
struct test {
  int year;// should take 4 byte
  string title;// how much bytes would take ? in my case taking 31 bytes ?
  double date;//should take 8 byte
  int month;// should take 4 byte
  } mine;

int main ()
{
 cout << " size is: "<<sizeof(mine);//printing 52 ?
 cout << " size is: "<<sizeof(struct test);//printing 52 ?
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The compiler adds padding for alignments..

Comment: Is that `string` = `std::string` or what? If it's a custom class / struct, you should post a trimmed-down version of the applicable class (it needn't contain more than the variables - no functions required).

Comment: have a look at #pragma pack and read about byte alignment.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Why compiler adds padding, i couldnt understand why compiler find it necessary to add padding bytes ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11770451/what-is-the-meaning-of-attribute-packed-aligned4/11772340#11772340

Comment: Your question is missing a "I expect it to print X", although it could probably be inferred that X = 4 + 31 + 8 + 4 = 47.

Comment: What about the string case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

```
sizeof(struct) >= sizeof(its members)
```

Because each member might be aligned to the lowest address after the previous member that satisfies:

```
mod(address/sizeof(member)) == 0
```

For example, consider this `struct`:

```
struct s {
   char c;
   int i[2];
   double d;
}
```

The memory might look like that:

```
+-------------------------------------------------+
| c |  |  |  | i[0] | i[1] |  |  |  |  | .. v ..  |
+-------------------------------------------------+
     ^  ^  ^                ^  ^  ^  ^
```

Comment: Does it really have to be aligned at its size? I believe in general, alignment requirements could be different.

Comment: @Angew I think you're right.. I'll look into that and will edit my answer, thank you.

Comment: @Angew Obviously not.  `struct X { char x[1000000]; }` does not require an alignment of a million (or more).  The alignment cannot be greater than the size, however.