# what happens in when we use pragma pack(1)?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma pack(1)

typedef struct 
{
  char name[10];
  int age;
  int class;
  char grade;
}stud_s;

int main(void)
{
  stud_s s1= {"john" ,10, 10, 'A'};
  printf("%ld \n",sizeof(stud_s));
  return 0;
}
```

In the above structure the name is reserved 10 bytes. And the name "john" is 4 bytes so when I use `#pragma` the size of structure should be 13. Instead the size resulted in 19 bytes. Could anyone have a look at my code? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Because 10 + 4 + 4 + 1 = 19 (at least in my trip through academia). Structure size is settled at *compile* time; not *run* time. Packed or not makes no difference in that fact.

Comment: @WhozCraig: The confusion is because they think that because `"john"` is only 4 bytes (which it isn't), then they would save 6 bytes in `stud_s::name`. Thus `19 - 6 = 13` as suggested in the question.

Comment: In that case what am I supposed to do get the size of the structure as 13.

Comment: @user3770743 Nothing. You can't. Unless you invent your own dynamic serialization buffer (or use someone else's, and either way, no small task) you're limited to compile-time sizing, packed or not. What is the *real* problem? Why does that structure with the name "John" need to be 13 bytes *exactly* ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11770451/what-is-the-meaning-of-attribute-packed-aligned4/11772340#11772340

Answer (score 0):

You're slightly confused as to what `pragma pack` does. It doesn't care about a particular instantiation, but about the padding in between elements.

Let's look at a simpler object:

```
struct obj {
    uint64_t x;
    uint32_t y;
};
```

Normally, this object will take **16 bytes**. If you use `pragma pack(1)`, it will only use **12 bytes**.

Answer (score 0):

In C it is not possible to define a structure containing an array whose size depends on the contents of the initializer.  You could use a C99 flexible array member, but then you would have to allocate the structure using `malloc`.

In C++ you could perhaps do something clever with templates and inheritance, but then the `name` member would not be part of the base type, which would be inconvenient.

In neither case does `#pragma pack` help.  That common extension only removes padding *in between* structure fields.