# Not sure I understand this line: "struct x {void (*y)(struct x *z);}"

Tags: c, struct, void

I'm looking through the code of a simple USB driver, and I've come across a line that I don't really understand:

```
struct UsbDevice
{
    ...
    void (*DeviceDetached)(struct UsbDevice *device) __attribute__((aligned(4)));
    ...
};
```

What exactly is happening here? This use of the parentheses (to...assign a new name to *device?) and this use of "void" are both new to me. (And the self-referencing struct is also odd.)

Comment: Except for the `__attribute__` (which is legacy, as C now provides `_Alignas`) this is all explained in every C book and standard C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This declares a function pointer, called `DeviceDetached`, that returns `void` and takes a pointer to a `struct UsbDevice`. The `__attribute__((aligned(4)))` forces alignment on a four-byte boundary. You can use the C11 `_Alignas`.

See [What is the meaning of "__attribute__((packed, aligned(4))) "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11770451/what-is-the-meaning-of-attribute-packed-aligned4) for more information on `__attribute((aligned(4))`.

Comment: Thanks! This makes a lot more sense now.

Answer (score 1):

This declares a field in the struct which is a function pointer.

```
void (*DeviceDetached)(struct UsbDevice *device)
^^^^  ^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^       ^^^^^^^
 |    |   field name        argument list
 |    |
 |    +- pointer type
 |
 +- return type
```

Note that *all* the parentheses are *required* to designate this as a function pointer. It is more common to `typedef` the function pointer type and then use the typedef'd name to declare struct fields or variables.

The `__attribute__` part is a GCC extension to C to indicate that the field should be aligned on a 4-byte boundary, regardless of what the "natural" alignment of the type would be. C11 has a standardised mechanism for this (`_Alignas`) but compilers have only recently started supporting this.