# Packing a union of structs

Tags: c, arrays, linker, usb, unions

I would like to create an array of different structs with different sizes.

The resulting array must be tightly packed with no null values between structs.

The whole thing must be initialised at compile time, so it can reside in the flash of an embedded system.

The result is a tree of USB configuration descriptors, every descriptor packed in immediately after the last to produce a single configuration blob. Suggestions of different approaches to the problem would be welcomed. http://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb5.shtml#ConfigurationDescriptors

```
struct a {
    uint16_t some_field;
};
struct b {
    uint32_t another_field;
};
union detail {
    struct a a;
    struct b b;
};
const union detail configuration[] = {
    { .a = { .some_field = 23 } },
    { .b = { .another_field = 12 } }
};
```

The above example is a significantly simplified version of my current, failing, attempt. Each element of the array is the size of the largest union member. So every array member is 32 bits and the first entry is padded with zeros.

Current output `1700 0000 0c00 0000`

Desired output `1700 0c00 0000`

Existing methods to generate this packed output use a giant uint8 array with macros to insert more complex values such as 16 bit numbers.
An array of structs more accurately represents the data and provides type safety, if it would work.

I don't need to be able to index or access the data from the array, the blob is shoved in to low level USB routines. Playing with the gcc packed attribute did not change the standard union array behaviour.

Comment: This problem is one of the reasons why structs/unions shouldn't be used for serialization.

Comment: Unions don't work like that.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas on having a single large struct.
Unfortunately the full structure depends on the configuration, one configuration may have 1 endpoint, another may have three, where each endpoint is another struct.
GCC doesn't support nesting structs with variable length arrays and making them a fixed size would defeat reusability.

Comment: All the elements of an array must be the same size.  That's because the code used to access the Nth element adds N x size of one element to the base address of the array.  If the elements are different sizes, that simply doesn't work.  It's one of the reasons you can't have an array of a structure type that has a flexible array member.

Comment: the `union` modifier means the structs occupy the same memory, So setting a field in one struct steps on one or more fields in the other struct.  A much better data representation would be each struct be a separate instance, then have an array of pointers, where each pointer points to one of the struct instances

Comment: Having all the different sized structs be packed together will result in numerous unaligned memory fetches.  This will slow down the running of the code rather dramatically. in an embedded system, better to have the runtime be fast rather than try to squeeze the memory footprint to the minimum size

Comment: in general, better to get the application working correctly, THEN work on time and memory optimizations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accepting comments from @Basile-Starynkevitch, @Jonathan-Leffler and others that what I was hoping for couldn't be done I reconsidered. What I really required was to precisely control the relative placement of the structures in memory/flash. The placement is done with the linker and I eventually found a solution there.

First, inside the SECTIONS portion of the linker script I created a special block. The only way to ensure order is to create multiple sections and manually order them, cpack0-3 in this instance.

```
.text : ALIGN(4) /* Align the start of the block */
{
    *(.cpack0) *(.cpack1) *(.cpack2) *(.cpack3)
} > MFlash32
```

Then the struct variables are slotted in to the special sections. The long handed syntax repetitive can be simplified by #define elements in a real implementation.

```
const struct a configuration __attribute__((section(".cpack0"), aligned(1))) = {
    .some_field = 23
};

const struct b configuration1 __attribute__((section(".cpack1"), aligned(1))) = {
    .another_field = 12
};
```

So we have a configuration variable, aligned at a 4 byte address for nice access and defined using a struct for type safety. The subsequent portions of the configuration are also defined by structs for safety and placed in memory sequentially. The `aligned(1)` attribute ensures that they are packed in tightly with no empty space.

This solves my problem, the configuration definition is done via a struct for all the advantages is provides, the ugliness is hidden by a `#define` and the final configuration is a binary blob of variable length accessed by a `uint8_t*` pointer. As the pointer increments it moves seamlessly across the different configuration elements.

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to create an array of different structs with different sizes.

That is simply not possible in C (and for good reasons). An array (in C) is made of components of the *same* size (and type). If that was not the case, indexed access to element of that array would be a very complex and time consuming operation (which is against the spirit of C; however in C++ you might define your own `operator []`).

You could instead have an array of `char`-s (e.g. `const char data[] = {0x35, 0x27, 0};` etc; perhaps that big array of bytes could be generated by some ad-hoc script emitting some C code initializing a large array) and have some [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) routine to process it. Or you could have an array of *pointers*:

```
union detail {
  struct a* aptr;
  struct b* bptr;
};

static const struct a firstelem= {.some_field= 35};
static const struct b secondelem= {.another_field= 12};
const union detail configuration[] = {
  {.aptr= &firstelem},
  {.bptr= &secondelem},
};
```

Notice that in your case having an array of pointers is actually giving a bigger data.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `union` for this, it doesn't do what you think it does. If you want an array of structs, where each struct may be of different type, it can't be done. Instead you will have to define a "super struct" containing all the other structs, in the correct order.

However, this doesn't solve the problem with alignment/padding. In order to disable padding in structs (and unions), you must resort to non-standard C. A common non-standard extension is `#pragma pack`. The gcc compiler also supports a non-standard attribute "packed", see [What is the meaning of “**attribute**((packed, aligned(4))) ”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11770451/what-is-the-meaning-of-attribute-packed-aligned4). Since code that disables padding is non-standard, it is also non-portable.

It is also possible to solve the problem by creating an array of `uint8_t` and then read/write chunks of data into this array. This is known as serialization/de-serialization of data. Conversions from any pointer type to `uint8_t*` or character types is safe, but unfortunately, going the other way around invokes undefined behavior. This is because of a bug in the C language often referred to as ["the strict aliasing rule"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule), which sometimes makes it impossible to use the C language in smooth or meaningful ways when doing hardware-related programming such as this.

The work-around for this C language bug is to write a gigantic union with 2 elements, one which is the `uint8_t` array, one which is a "super struct" like the one described above. You won't actually use the super struct - you probably can't because of padding - but by putting it in a union you invoke a special exception to strict aliasing. Meaning there will no longer be undefined behavior and you will prevent aggressive optimizing compilers like gcc from breaking your code.

Another gcc-specific work-around for this C language bug is to compile with `gcc -fno-strict-aliasing`. Embedded systems compilers typically work better than gcc for this case, since they don't follow the C standard, but instead make pointer conversions behave deterministically in a non-standard manner. For example, on such compilers code like `(uint16_t*)my_uint8t` deterministically treats the pointed-at data as `uint16_t`, rather than silently causing your program to crash and burn.