# What does the PACKED keyword mean in Android aosp?

Tags: android, c++, build, android-source

When I read some C++ code in the Android aosp, I see some classes are declared with a `PACKED` keyword. For example, in `<android_source_root>/art/runtime/image.h`, a class `ImageSection` is declared this way:

```
class PACKED(4) ImageSection {
 public:
  ImageSection() : offset_(0), size_(0) { }
  ImageSection(uint32_t offset, uint32_t size) : offset_(offset), size_(size) { }
  ImageSection(const ImageSection& section) = default;
  ImageSection& operator=(const ImageSection& section) = default;
```

What does the `PACKED(4)` mean?

Comment: Its related to padding see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11772340/10035556

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is defined in `<android_source_root>/art/libartbase/base/macros.h`

```
#define PACKED(x) __attribute__ ((__aligned__(x), __packed__))
```